# How to install Imo messenger in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: wine

I downloaded an Imo messenger installer (for Windows) and executed it with WINE. I got a desktop shortcut, but it does not work. When I double-click it, it hangs around for a while (I can see it in the task bar), but then disappears. I do not get anything in the desktop. I am using an HP Pavilion desktop. I know that there are other programs (skype, etc.), but I need namely Imo messenger.

Comment: Well, I think you are out of luck here. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9927 suggests that the imo Messenger is unlikely to work on Wine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed your link, saw the wine/imo page. Could not draw any conclusions...

Comment: 1. you can try wine or crossover.
2. you can install imo inside the virtual machine.